# Rapidly duplicate images on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

How can I fast duplicate images located in a folder?

I usually used this command:

```
cp -R -p path/to/folder path/to/another/folder
```

But, because of high number of images in `path/to/folder`, operation takes too much time.

How can I done this task faster? Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Put them on ZFS and use snapshots/clones instead of copying?